# Presimplify topojson from command line

Tags: javascript, topojson

As far as I understand `topojson.presimplify(JSON)` in D3 adds `Z` coordinate to each point in the input topojson shape based on its significance, which then allows to use it for the dynamic simplification like in http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/6245977

This method `topojson.presimplify()` takes quite a long time to execute on complicated maps, especially in Firefox which makes the browser unresponsive for few seconds.

Can it be baked directly into the topojson file via the command line as it is done with projections:

```
topojson --projection 'd3.geo.mercator().translate([0,0]).scale(1)' -o cartesian.topo.json spherical.topo.json
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a workaround for this which is not completely as simple as I wanted but still achieves the same result.

After the `topojson.presimplify(data)` is called, `data` already holds the pre simplified geometry with added `Z` axis values.

Then I convert it to the JSON string and manually copy it to a new file with `JSON.stringify(data)`

Nevertheless these conversion to a JSON string has a problem with `Infinity` values which often occur for `Z` and with `JSON.stringify` method are converted to `null`. Also when there is a value for `Z` coordinate it is usually too precise and writing all decimal points takes too much space.

For that reason before converting `data` to a JSON string I trim the numbers:

```
// Simplifying the map
topojson.presimplify(data);

// Changing Infinity values to 0, limiting decimal points
var arcs = data.arcs;
for(var i1 = arcs.length; i1--;) {
    var arc = arcs[i1];
    for(var i2 = arc.length; i2--;) {
        var v = arc[i2][2];
        if(v === Infinity) arc[i2][2] = 0;
        else {
            arc[i2][2] = M.round(v * 1e9)/1e9;
        }
    }
}
```

This makes `Infinity` values to appear as exactly `0` and other values are trimmed to 9 decimal points which is enough for dynamic simplification to work properly.

Since such string is too long to easily print it for copying to the new json file it is much easier to store it in the localStorage of the browser:

```
localStorage.setItem(<object name>, JSON.stringify(data))
```

Then in Safari or Chrome open the developer console and in the tab `Resources -> Local Storage -> <Website URL>` the stored object can be found, copied and then pasted into a text editor.

Usually it is pasted as a `<key> <value>` pair, so one needs to remove  from the beginning of the pasted string so that it starts from `{`.

Since `Infinity` values have been converted to `0`, in the dynamic simplification function it should be taken into account so that points with `Z = 0` are treated as `Z = Infinity` and are always plotted with any simplification area:

```
point: function(x, y, z) { 
    if (z===0 || z >= simplificationArea) {
        this.stream.point(x, y); 
    }
}
```